# Sharing "stats class" between many classes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my mobile class, which will define players, enemies, well mobiles...
I have an item class, which is self-explanatory...

Let's say for the sake of the example that we have three stats,

```
-> Strength
-> Dexterity
-> Intelligence
```

I was planning to have theses stats on my mobiles, and on my items, if on my items they are different from 0, they therefore are modifiers of my mobiles.

How should I store these in my classes ?

Should it be like this :

```
MY_Item
{   
  var $stats_dex;
  var $stats_int;
  var $stats_str;
}
```

Or maybe have another class, "Stats class" that every other class would have too... ?

```
MY_Item
{
  var $stats = new MY_Stats;
}
```

Same for my mobiles ?

Because in my mobiles, I'll have to compute the equiped items too... So I would end up with something like :

```
class MY_Mobile
{   
  var $stats_dex;
  var $stats_int;
  var $stats_str;
  var $modifier_stats_dex;
  var $modifier_stats_int;
  var $modifier_stats_str;
}
```

Right now I'm working with the first prototype, but I'm already feeling uneasy about it...

Comment: Have you looked into using `trait`s that seems like the right tool for the job.

Comment: I am currently unknown of the "traits" thing you're mentionning. I'll do some search.

Comment: I think I would go with a separate stats class ,inheriting CI_Model (or MY_Model if you already have extended CI_Model with your own) and have the other classes inherit the stats class.

Comment: Inheritance is likely a poor choice for a set of behaviors that are not intrinsic to the 'leaf' class. For example, I have a speed (stat), and my new Nike shoes have a +1 speed (stat). However, I inherit from 'actor' or 'animal', while my shoes carry none of that lineage. Traits, the Decorator design pattern, or interfaces are superior choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple answer is that this is where methods come in handy. If your "business rule" is that a mobile's stat is the sum of the native stat and all modifications that items would make, then my recommendation is to give stats to both mobile and items (more on that later) and then give your mobile class a method such as `getStat($statName)` which is responsible for doing the summing. This might be called the 'facade' design pattern (you present a clean interface to the outside world, obscuring the detail that items modify stats). To pull this off cleanly, mark your member properties as protected or private and only allow the other parts of the app to use the getter.

With respect to the question of giving multiple classes many of the same properties/behaviors, there are several options. The most basic (and probably wrong in this case) is to give them a common ancestor, such as 'statableEntity'. This is a poor choice because PHP is a inheritance language, and being statable is not inherent to your classes.

The second choice is PHP's relatively new feature called Traits. This is a fair bit better than class inheritance, because it starts to feel like multiple inheritance. This is a good option if the behavior is literally identical no matter which class needs the trait.

The third choice is to use an interface. In this option, all classes implementing the interface need to have the same methods, but they do not all need to use the same code in the method body. This is a good choice when the classes adhering to the interface might want to implement the behaviors a little differently.

I think in your case, I recommend interfaces, because a person's stats may respond to context in different ways compared to the same stat on an item (for example, maybe the current value of an item's stat is reduced because the item is 'old' or 'needs repair', or the stat on a person changes with hunger, etc.).

Comment: Thank you, I've read a bit about traits and thought that it would do the trick. But now that you're mentionning interface, I'll have to look about them too.

As for your point about the protected, private, getstats and such, they are in fact in the project to be like that, but, since it's the first tests, I didn't quite do it "properly" :). Onto read for interfaces !

Comment: I'm not yet quite sure about interfaces... Are they only defining some "must do" that my class must have ? All exemples I'm reading/finding seems to be like that. Defining the interface, explaining the methods, constants that there is in that interface, then in each and every class that the interface is implemented, we re-define the methods and use it? Thanks.

Comment: @SantaClauss that's correct. It's for classes that your application needs to treat in a consistent way (by relying on the 'must have' methods) but which can decide for themselves what implementing the methods means.

Comment: Would having a traits fullfill the interface must-have methods ? Although this might be stupid to have both of them... ?

Comment: I think so. But the 'contract' nature of having the interface is fulfilled by having the trait. That is, traits are compile-time in PHP, so there is really no added benefit to the Interface. In both cases, you can type-hint and/or reflect on the object to determine that it has the methods you are after. The difference is more about "Do they share just the interface? Or do they share an identical implementation as well?"

Comment: If you think there is good reason to allow different classes to have different implementations, then interfaces are good. However, keep in mind that any class can override methods from a Trait.

Comment: All right thanks for the good insight. I think I will go with `traits` considering that my mobile, and items, will both have stats values. Now I just need to see where to put `traits` in code igniter :). Thanks a lot for your informations !